# Reference multiple schema in a single schema

Tags: swagger-editor, swaggerhub

In swaggerhub I am trying to build a restful API. For which I have created n number of POJOs for request. I would like to represent them as references in other POJO example:

```
 ClientInformation:
   type: object
   schema:
     $ref: '#/definitions/EditClient'
     $ref: '#/definitions/OtherDetails' #Duplicate mapping key error I see at this line
    properties:
      notes:
      type: string
      example: This is a test
      description: A description
```

I tried `,` but didn't work. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ClientInformation` is a merger of the `EditClient` and `OtherDetails` schemas, you need `allOf`:

```yaml
ClientInformation:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/definitions/EditClient'
    - $ref: '#/definitions/OtherDetails'
    - type: object
      properties:
        notes:
          type: string
          example: This is a test
          description: A description
```

If `ClientInformation` has properties that are instances of other schemas, you can `$ref` the property schemas as follows:

```yaml
ClientInformation:
  type: object
  properties:
    notes:
      type: string
      example: This is a test
      description: A description
    foo:
      $ref: '#/definitions/EditClient'
    bar:
      $ref: '#/definitions/OtherDetails'
```